# Why $ doesn't match \r\n

Tags: ruby, regex

Can someone explain this:

```
str = "hi there\r\n\r\nfoo bar"

rgx = /hi there$/
str.match rgx # => nil

rgx = /hi there\s*$/
str.match rgx # => #<MatchData "hi there\r\n\r">
```

On the one hand it seems like `$` does not match `\r`.  But then if I first capture all the white spaces, which also include `\r`, then `$` suddenly does appear to match the second `\r`, not continuing to capture the trailing `"\nfoo bar"`.

Is there some special rule here about consecutive `\r\n` sequences? The docs on `$` simply say it will match "end of line" which doesn't explain this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is a zero-width assertion. It doesn't match any character, it matches at a *position*. Namely, it matches either immediately before a `\n`, or at the end of string.

`/hi there\s*$/` matches because `\s*` matches `"\r\n\r"`, which allows the `$` to match at the position before the second `\n`. The `$` could have also matched at the position before the first `\n`, but the `\s*` is greedy and matches as much as it can, while still allowing the overall regex to match.

Comment: Bottom line issue: \r is not matched by $ nor is "\r\n" even though puts and other things do understand them together as a newline for the purpose of display.